# Change of passport details with ref to Australia Visa

Tags: visas, australia

I hold a Business Visa for Australia issued last year on 18th of May 2018. I have a new passport issued on 25th Feb 2019. I have applied for updation in my visa by filling form 929 on 8th of May. Nothing has happened in last 2 weeks . I have to urgently reach Melbourne due to some business emergency

Comment: i have the same problem with you. The estimated time curently is 40 days but me and my friend need to go to Australia by the end of this month. Did you get update from this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, Australia does not send a response after your Form 929 change is processed.

To know if your visa has been transferred, you can check the status of your Australia visa in [VEVO](https://online.immi.gov.au/evo/firstParty?actionType=query) by entering your passport details of your new passport.

Comment: Well thanks Michael , I have already done all that. And when I put my new passport details , it’s showing a error. Whereas when I put my old passport no , it still shows the details of visa as per the old passport.

Comment: I have also written to Australian Immigration at Contact us giving my email details. But there’s no response from them as well.